# How do I make multiple divs accept drag and drop images?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

*example* http://jsfiddle.net/7DeFn/1

```
<div id="container">       
    <body>
        <div id="clone_wrapper">
            <div class="right">
                <div id="pricebox1">
                    <div id="pricebox2">
                        <input id="coin" type="text" id="text" name="text_name" style="width: 35px; style=" height: 21px; maxlength=3 />
                        <div id="selectbox1">
                            <div id="selectbox2">
                                <div id="selectbox3">
                                    <select name="qty">
                                        <option value="Each" selected>Each</option>
                                        <option value="All"> All</option>
                                        <option value="Any 2">Any 2</option>
                                        <option value="Any 3">Any 3</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="pricebox3">
                            <div id="pricebox4">
                                <div id="pricebox5"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="clone_wrapper">
            <div class="right">
                <div id="pricebox1">
                    <div id="pricebox2">
                        <input id="coin" type="text" id="text" name="text_name" style="width: 35px; style=" height: 21px; maxlength=3 />
                        <div id="selectbox1">
                            <div id="selectbox2">
                                <div id="selectbox3">
                                    <select name="qty">
                                        <option value="Each" selected>Each</option>
                                        <option value="All"> All</option>
                                        <option value="Any 2">Any 2</option>
                                        <option value="Any 3">Any 3</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="pricebox3">
                            <div id="pricebox4">
                                <div id="pricebox5"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>         
        <div id='inventrightside1'><div id='inventrightside2'><p1><img src="images/invent1.png "/></p>
<select id="filter"><option>Select Item</option>
    <option value="glasses" />Glasses<br />
    <option value="afro" />Afros<br />
    <option value="alien" />Alien<br />
    <option value="antler" />Antlers<br />
    <option value="army" />Army<br />
</select>
<div class="inventholding">
                    <div id="itembox1">
                        <div id="itembox3">
                            <div id="itembox4">
                                <img src="images/3dglasses_black.png" class="glasses" id="price" alt="Black 3D Glasses" />
                                <img src="images/3dglasses_white.png" class="glasses" id="price" alt="White 3D Glasses" />
                                <img src="images/afro_black.png" class="afro" id="price" alt="Black Afro" />
                                <img src="images/afro_blue.png" class="afro" id="price" alt="Blue Afro" />
                                <img src="images/afro_green.png" class="afro" id="price" alt="Green Afro" />
                                <img src="images/afro_orange.png" class="afro" id="price" alt="Orange Afro" />
                                <img src="images/afro_pink.png" class="afro" id="price" alt="Pink Afro" />
                                <img src="images/afro_purple.png" class="afro" id="price" alt="Purple Afro" />
                                <img src="images/afro_rainbow.png" class="afro" id="price" alt="Rainbow Afro" />
                                <img src="images/afro_red.png" class="afro" id="price" alt="Red Afro" />
                                <img src="images/afro_white.png" class="afro" id="price" alt="White Afro" />
                                <img src="images/alienhead_blue.png" class="alien" id="price" alt= "Blue Alien Head" />
                                <img src="images/alienhead_brown.png" class="alien" id="price" alt= "Brown Alien Head" />
                                <img src="images/alienhead_green.png" class="alien" id="price" alt= "Green Alien Head" />
                                <img src="images/alienhead_grey.png" class="alien" id="price" alt= "Grey Alien Head" />
                                <img src="images/alienhead_purple.png" class="alien" id="price" alt= "Purple Alien Head" />
                                <img src="images/alienhead_red.png" class="alien" id="price" alt= "Red Alien Head" />
                                <img src="images/antlers_brown.png" class="antler" id="price" alt="Brown Antler" />
                                <img src="images/antlers_gold.png" class="antler" id="price" alt="Gold Antler" />
                                <img src="images/armytrousers_black.png" class="army" id="price" alt="Black Army Pants" />
                                <img src="images/armytrousers_blue.png" class="army" id="price" alt="Blue Army Pants" />
                                <img src="images/armytrousers_green.png" class="army" id="price" alt="Green Army Pants" />
                                <img src="images/armytrousers_pink.png" class="army" id="price" alt="Pink Army Pants" />
                                <img src="images/armytrousers_purple.png" class="army" id="price" alt="Purple Army Pants" />
                                <img src="images/armytrousers_sand.png" class="army" id="price" alt="Sand Army Pants" />

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

function itemInSpot(drag_item,spot)
{
var oldSpotItem = $(spot).find('img');
if(oldSpotItem.length>100) {
    oldSpotItem.appendTo('#itembox4').draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });
}
var item = $('<img />');
item.attr('src',drag_item.attr('src')).attr('class',drag_item.attr('class')).appendTo(spot).draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });
drag_item.remove(); // remove the old object
}

 $(document).ready(function() {
$("img").draggable({ revert: 'invalid'});

$("#itembox4").droppable()
$("#pricebox5").droppable({ accept: 'img'})
$('#pricebox5').droppable({ accept: 'img'});
$('#pricebox5,#pricebox5,#itembox4').bind('drop', function(ev,ui) {  itemInSpot(ui.draggable,this); });
 $('#itembox4 img').hide();
$('#clone_button').click(function() {
    $('#clone_wrapper div:#pricebox5')
        .clone()
        .append('')
        .appendTo($('#clone_wrapper'));
})
});
$(function() {$('#filter').change(function(){
    $('#itembox4 img').hide();
    $('.'+$(this).val()).show();});
});


$(function() {$('#button').click(function () {
    var clone = $('#pricebox1').clone().appendTo('#container');
    clone.find('[new*="one"]').attr('class', 'one');
    clone.find('[new*="two"]').attr('class', 'two');
    clone.find('[new*="three"]').attr('class', 'three');
    clone.find('[id]').removeAttr('id');
});});
```

**What am I trying to achieve?**
I'm Trying to create 4-5 boxes for users to add any images in to selected boxes.

**Whats the problem(s)?**
When I copy and paste the pricebox only the first box allows images to be dragged and dropped into them no mater what I try and do.
**What functions do I need to keep?**
Images need to remain as drag and drop.
Images should be able to go back and forth through any boxes inventory/pricebox/new price boxes.
All images must remain under a filter.

Thanking anyone in advance who can help me fix this problem.

**Fixed myself**
I ended up changing the `#pricebox5` to `.pricebox5` and it allowed them to enter along with changing the jquery.